# Implementing autocomplete in HTML input

Tags: html, autocomplete

I devise a web site. I am using PHP, XML and HTML. There is input forms in my HTML files and I want to implement auto-suggestion in input forms. 
When you enter search phrase to google's input form, many suggestions appeared in your browser. I exactly want to implement this.

What must I do? Which language/interface/information I need to?

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Autocomplete is done via JavaScript. Check out the [jQuery Autocomplete plugin](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/autocomplete) for a pretty easily library to get started with. You can either include the values to be used for autocomplete in the JavaScript, or you can make an AJAX request to a PHP script which provides suggestions. Feel free to comment if you'd like more help.

Answer (score 0):

This will be the easiest way to get it done...

http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/

Answer (score 0):

JQuery UI is a javascript framework that has a nice autocomplete implementation: http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/

Of course you will need the jquery and jquery ui javascript frameworks.